# Segmented line only draws first segment on iPhone. Works perfectly in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to draw a segmented line with openGL in iOS. It works on the simulator but not on the iPhone. Here's the draw method:

```
- (void) draw
{
    if(nuPoints_ <= 1)
        return;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture_ name]);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords_);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colorPointer_);

    BOOL newBlend = blendFunc_.src != CC_BLEND_SRC || blendFunc_.dst != CC_BLEND_DST;
    if( newBlend )
        glBlendFunc( blendFunc_.src, blendFunc_.dst );

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, nuPoints_*2);

    if( newBlend )
        glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
```

}

(blendFunc isn't set to anything)

vertices_ and nuPoints both have the correct (amount of) points, so the problem is definatly in this method.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Okay. If you had I was going suggest answering your own question. MAybe I'll try to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong you the code you pasted, so something must be wrong before or after this.

Try and put something like this after the draw

```
        GLenum err = glGetError();
        if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            NSLog(@"Render Error 0x%04X", err);
        }
```

And see if any GL errors pop up, I always keep one of these commented out on my main draw loop, it has saved me many times.